# How the desktop identify the correct time when power on the system

Tags: operating-systems, runtime

I bit confuse with how the desktop identify correct time when i power on again, i was surprised how it happen? is there anything run even when i power off the system? Let say in my time it was 7.30 p.m i power off the system and then again morning i power on the system i found the time was updated properly as 10.00 a.m i was surprised how it works, for installing the system with new os also it request timezone once i set it properly trigger the correct time? I haven't connect with internet or any? I was surprised there is something run in background always to overcome this problem? Please Advise if any

Thanks,
vicky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On any motherboard, there is a battery which powers the internal clock. When you shut down your computer, including when you unplug it, the clock is still going. If you let your machine unplugged for a few years, then the battery will drain and you'll be required to adjust the clock in BIOS during the next boot (as well as other options).